# I want to show file name from database column but in table column there is employee_id, Date, and file_id also in the same column

Tags: sql, angularjs

I want to show file name like "3.pdf" or "1021 kha.txt" but in the database column, it exists like "000001_07032018 052035__3.pdf" or "000001_07032018 052111__1021_kha.txt".  as I am an internee I want to know what should I write in angularJS to show only file name on front-end.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh - Ahmed is looking to extract name of the file from a string having a pattern "__"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in MySQL:

```
select substr("000001_07032018 052111__1021_kha.txt", instr("000001_07032018 052111__1021_kha.txt", "__") + 2, LENGTH("000001_07032018 052111__1021_kha.txt") - instr("000001_07032018 052111__1021_kha.txt", "__"))
```

With SET option:

```
SET @str = '000001_07032018 052035__3.pdf';
select substr( @str, instr( @str, "__") + 2, LENGTH( @str) - instr( @str, "__"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal javascript like this:

```
let fileName = val.split("__").pop().replace("_", " ");
```